# Include javascript with resources via h:outputScript

Tags: javascript, jsf, jscolor

I would like to include JScolor to my jsf application. It is possible via `<script>` tag, but I mean it is more system via `<h:outputScript>`.

However it is not working with resources. JSColor includes one js file and some picture files - it seems like the js file is included and the reousrces not.

Could anybody tell me why? And how to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The JS file is apparently referencing picture files via a relative path which do not represent a valid JSF resource URL.

The `<h:outputScript>` generates a JSF resource URL which goes through the JSF resource handler which worries about among others automatic localization and versioning. It would generate an URL prefixed with `/javax.faces.resource` and also append the currently used `FacesServlet` URL mapping such as `*.xhtml` or `/faces/*`.

Thus, if you mapped the faces servlet on `*.xhtml` and have a `/resources/jscolor` folder with the JS and image files and have referenced the JS file as follows,

```
<h:outputScript name="jscolor/jscolor.js" />
```

then it would generate

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/context/javax.faces.resource/jscolor/jscolor.js.xhtml"></script>
```

However, the image files are not physically available in `/javax.faces.resource/jscolor` folder, instead they are physically available in `/resources/jscolor` folder. The `/javax.faces.resource` would only be automatically resolved when you apply the faces servlet mapping on the resource name. Thus, this specific case would only work if you manually edit the `jscolor.js` file to change image file names from e.g. `arrow.gif` to `arrow.gif.xhtml`.

If you don't utilize any automatic localization or versioning features of the JSF resource resolver, nor are using any special custom resource resolvers which requires real JSF resources rather than static HTML elements, such as [this one](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler), then you can also just go ahead with a plain vanilla HTML `<script>` element instead of a `<h:outputScript>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I may misunderstand your question, but this snippet will help:

```
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/path/on/WebContent/foo.js"></script>
```

I regularly use this kind of java resource include, instead of the `<h:outputScript>`

Comment: It is interesting to hear as to *why* you are using this technique *instead* of a standard one? What if you need some EL expression inside?

Comment: As BlausC mentioned before: the `<h:outputScript>` generates `<script type="text/javascript" src="/context/javax.faces.resource/...`. That is regularly not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your js file's path (file named jquery.js) into `resources/js` folder like that:

```
resources/js/jquery.js
```

Then you have to write:

```
<h:outputScript name="./js/jquery.js"  target="body"/>
```

PS. Pay attention on attribute target (eg head, body)

Answer (score 0):

add in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you add some text explaining why this should be tried and what it is intended to do?